# ggplot delete specific x-axis labels when facetting

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(200)
df <- tibble(Date = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 16),
             Year = c(rep("2018", 12), rep("2019", 4)), 
             Values = c(runif(16, 20, 80)))

ggplot(df, aes(Date, Values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "month", 
               date_labels = "%b",
               expand = expand_scale(add = c(31, 31))) +
  facet_grid(~Year, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

How do I delete the unnecessary months that label my x-axis?

- `Dec` and `Jan` on my 2018 facet
- `Dec` and `May` on my 2019 facet

I played around with things like `breaks = df$Date` but that breaks (pardon the pun) my free scaling and free spacing on the facets. **And** I need to keep the `expand` argument, I want the extra space, not the extra month labels that come along with it.

**What I got**
[image: extra ggplot x axis months]

**What I want**
[image: extra ggplot x axis months removed]

Comment: Remove the `expand` argument?

Comment: Or decrease the amount added in the `expand` argument. You're adding 31 days to either end of the axis—the code you wrote does precisely what you're saying you *don't* want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I want the expanded space, but do not want the labels that come along with it. I should update my question with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that much control over the labels, then you should pass your own label function. Here's one way that might work. We basocally do what ggplot does by default and then replace the first/last non-NA value with a zero length string to hide the label

```
ggplot(df, aes(Date, Values)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = "month", 
               labels = function(x) {
                 lab <- scales::date_format("%b")(x)
                 lab[range(which(!is.na(lab)))] <- ""
                 lab
                },
               expand = expand_scale(add = c(31, 31))) +
  facet_grid(~Year, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit your code to be like that

```
set.seed(200)
df <-
  tibble(
    Date = seq(as.Date("2018/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 14),
    Year = c(rep("2018", 12), rep("2019", 4)),
    Values = c(runif(16, 20, 80))
  )

ggplot(df, aes(Date, Values)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "month",
               date_labels = "%b",) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[[image: a better visualization of what you want]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMuco.jpg)

Or you can edit the expand argument to be minus; to remove the padding which will remove the extra months you don't want to be shown

```
  scale_x_date(breaks = "month", 
                    date_labels = "%b",
                 expand = expand_scale(add = -1))
```

[image: The same chart without unneeded months]